# Updating lifetime

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I'm trying to figure out how to update the lifetime of the particles, so that its not so rigid and actually recycles smoothly and not in waves.

https://jsfiddle.net/jceisner/5rqwx26n/

```
function update {
 for(var i = 0; i < particles.length-25; i++){
// keep moving if still alive or still on screen
    if(particles[i].lifetime > 0 || particles[i].x < 0){
        particles[i].x -= particles[i].radius*0.5;
        particles[i].lifetime--; // must be --
} else {
    // reset particles
  particles[i].x = canvas.width;
  particles[i].lifetime = canvas.width;
  particles[i].y = Math.random()*canvas.height; //will randomize x position
  particles[i].radius;
  } 
 }
}
```

What am i missing???

Comment: Have you heard of [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)? You'll also want to track the timestamp from before the last update (`var lastUpdate = Date.now()`) and compare it to the current time to get a delta time. You can use that delta time to incrementally change positions and get smoother animation. [This is a good read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Anatomy) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Right now every particle shares the same lifetime, so all of them die at the same time. Hence the rigid reset.

Just take everything concerning lifetime out of your fiddle, and change the less than `if(particles[i].x < 0)` to greater than `if(particles[i].x > 0)`...

### *less foobar version:

Because I really liked the idea and had some time on my hand I rewrote the demo to be less foobar, make use of requestAnimationFrame, use camelCasing instead of under_scores etc... :)

```js
(function STARS() {
  "use strict";
  var canvas = document.getElementById("output");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var time = Date.now();
  var deltaTime = 0;
  var fps = 90;

  var particles = [];

  function particle() {
    var that = {
      x: Math.random() * canvas.width,
      y: Math.random() * canvas.height,
      radius: Math.random() * 5,
      speed: Math.random() * 0.9
    };

    return that;
  }

  function particleSystem(numParticles) {
    var i = numParticles;
    while (i) {
      particles.push(particle());
      i -= 1;
    }
  }
  particleSystem(100);

  function update() {
    var i = particles.length;
    while (i) {
      i -= 1;

      if (particles[i].x > 0) {
        particles[i].x -= particles[i].radius * 0.5;
      } else {
        particles[i].x = canvas.width;
        particles[i].y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
      }
    }
  }

  function draw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var i = particles.length;
    var par = undefined;
    while (i) {
      i -= 1;
      par = particles[i];

      context.fillStyle = "orange";
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(par.x, par.y, par.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
      context.stroke();
      context.fill();
    }
  }

  function gameLoop() {
    var now = Date.now();

    deltaTime += now - time;
    time = now;

    // cap deltaTime to one second to prevent freezing
    if (deltaTime > 1000) {
        deltaTime = 1000;
    }

    while (deltaTime > 1000 / fps) {
      update();

      deltaTime -= 1000 / fps;
    }

    draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  }
  gameLoop();
}());
```

```html
<canvas id="output" width="630px" height="180px"></canvas>
```